# ipv4 networking not enabled when runnig docker

Tags: python, docker, networking, portforwarding, ipv4

I have a remote machine at my workplace, when we developers run server/ or docker containers. everything was working fine but a while back somethign went wrong.

if I run the python flask app

```
from app import app
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5050)
```

i get message

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5050/
```

and I am able to access the above from my local machine using the remote server machine `ip:5050` but if I run docker container `docker run -itd  <conta_image_name> -p 80:90 --add-host=localdomain.com:machine_ip_address` i get error message saying `IPv4 forwarding is disabled. Networking will not work.`

Now this issue is in production so I really need someone to throw up some light, what might be wrong or let me know what more info I need to put.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Networking Disabled: WARNING: IPv4 forwarding is disabled. Networking will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453263/docker-networking-disabled-warning-ipv4-forwarding-is-disabled-networking-wil)

Comment: Why not have a search first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this issue myself following this: https://success.docker.com/article/ipv4-forwarding

Comment: Whatever this link went to no longer works. It directs to the home page now.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is..

Try adding -net=host  along with docker run command

https://medium.com/@gchandra/docker-ipv4-forwarding-is-disabled-8499ce59231e

Comment: You need to add disclosure when linking your own websites, tools, blogs, articles, etc. See [how not to be a spammer](/help/promotion)

Comment: Sure will do.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh - your article pointed the solution of --network=host on my docker build command using docker-in-docker on Gitlab. Worked like a charm.