# /bin/sh -c apk --no-cache returned non-zero code 4

Tags: docker, jenkins

Jenkins build is failing on all nodes except one
I am getting below error while building a docker image

```
Could not build image: The command '/bin/sh -c apk --no-cache update &&     apk --no-cache add python py-pip py-setuptools ca-certificates groff &&     pip --no-cache-dir install cfn-lint &&     pip --no-cache-dir install awscli==${AWS_CLI_VERSION}' returned a non-zero code: 4 -> [Help 1]
```

My docker file is

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

# Versions: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awscli#downloads
ENV AWS_CLI_VERSION 1.16.100

RUN apk --no-cache update && \
    apk --no-cache add python py-pip py-setuptools ca-certificates groff && \
    pip --no-cache-dir install cfn-lint && \
    pip --no-cache-dir install awscli==${AWS_CLI_VERSION}
```

How do I solve this issue ?

Comment: try with `RUN set -x && apk --no-cache update ...` you will see more info

Comment: If its only failing on one particular jenkins node then try to cleanup docker images from that node and retry again.

Comment: Just tested and it works for me. My advice is to try to break this `RUN` command into multiple `RUN` in order to figure out which command is returning error code `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested and it works for me, so it could be related to some networking issue. My advice is to try to break this `RUN` command into multiple `RUN` (or at least in two) in order to figure out which command is returning error code `4`.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

# Versions: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awscli#downloads
ENV AWS_CLI_VERSION 1.16.100

RUN apk --no-cache update && \
    apk --no-cache add python py-pip py-setuptools ca-certificates groff

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install cfn-lint && \
    pip --no-cache-dir install awscli==${AWS_CLI_VERSION}
```

### An hypothesis

Since `apk` uses `wget`

> In addition to local repositories, the apk utility uses busybox wget to fetch packages using http:, https: or ftp: protocols. The following is a valid repository file:

- https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management

The error code `4` could come from `wget` and, if it's so, it's meaning is

> Network failure.

- https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

So my guess is that some agents have no access to the location from where the packages are downloaded. Please check if you have access to `http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org` from these agents. To do so, try to run a `wget` in the `Dockerfile` with the first fetch made by `apk`.

```
RUN wget http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
```

Comment: I am getting this error :Step 3/5 : RUN apk --no-cache update &&     apk --no-cache add python py-pip py-                                                                             setuptools ca-certificates groff
 ---> [Warning] IPv4 forwarding is disabled. Networking will not work.

Comment: Good we have the confirmation, it's a networking issue. I'm not a specialist, you could have a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453263/docker-networking-disabled-warning-ipv4-forwarding-is-disabled-networking-wil

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and I had to remove invalid `proxies` entry from `~/.docker/config.json`.