# runnig docker in proxmox is missing networking functionality

Tags: docker, networking, containers, proxmox

in `Proxmox Virtual Environment 5.3-9` I run virtual machine

`Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic`

with docker version `Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d`

bridge `docker0` is installed

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.02426bdb101b   no
```

masquerading in iptables was set during install

```
 iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !localhost/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I also did https://stackoverflow.com/a/41453306/3358126

I can start container with `docker run -it ubuntu bash` and have shell access

Here my problem starts. Inside container there's no network present at all. I'm missing `ip, route, ping, ifconfig` commands.

`apt` nor `apt-get` will update. There's no editor installed so I can't change any files.

output of apt update comes after like 20 seconds timeout

```
apt update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease        
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                  
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

I have `/etc/resolv.conf` and the information seems correct:

```
nameserver 172.16.40.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search localdomain
```

Same way of installing docker on my Linux Mint produces working apt.

I'm fighting this second day, so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: could you create a container with `docker run --rm -dit --name test ubuntu bash` and while its running run a `docker inspect test` and then add that output to your question?

Comment: Also, whats the output of `apt update`?

Comment: At a high level what you're describing sounds more or less normal.  The `ubuntu` Docker image provides a minimal base to install more software; it's not a full interactive environment and it's usually not something you usually use directly.  The Docker daemon itself controls the network environment and you don't run `ifconfig` inside a container.

Comment: @DavidMaze 1) what do you mean by "not fully interactive"? you can very much run any command interactively, in this specific case it will be like any other bash-commandline. 2) it does not sound normal, since it seems as if the daemon does not provide a network, at least none that connects to the internet 3) you can absolutely run ifconfig inside a docker container if you want to debug the containers network connection.

Comment: @joppich output from `docker inspect test`  https://gist.github.com/PavelNiedoba/80661caa3d6715b624787c7ab60e6692

Comment: @PavelNiedoba that looks regular. Since you were able to pull the ubuntu image, i'm gonna assume the underlying VMs network works fine. could you run an `ip a` on it? i'd also suggest building an image with `iproute2`, `dns-tools`, `net-tools` etc on a different host and then `docker export` that into the VM, so you can debug properly.