# Cannot get port-mapping to work with Shiny on Docker with Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: docker, shiny, digital-ocean

I am trying to get a Shiny application working as a web server on a Digital Ocean droplet, using a docker image by rocker. All seems to be working fine, but somehow I cannot access the page through a browser.

Docker seems properly exposed to port 80 on the droplet:
[image]

R seems to correctly listen to port 80 inside the docker container:
[image]

Docker process listing looks correct:
[image]

As does the machine listing:
[image]

The command by which I started the container is:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name ggplotgui jelkink/fpr
```

My Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM rocker/shiny:latest
COPY . /srv/shiny-server/docker
RUN sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev xdg-utils
RUN sudo R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'dplyr', 'plotly', 
'rmarkdown', 'ggplot2', 'readxl', 'haven', 'rio', 'stringr', 'readr', 
'devtools'))"
RUN chmod +x /srv/shiny-server/docker/continuous_shiny_run.sh
EXPOSE 80

CMD /srv/shiny-server/docker/continuous_shiny_run.sh
```

Although, to be honest, I also didn't manage to get it work under my local Docker installation, so perhaps it's unrelated to DigitalOcean.

Running the nginx hello world example on DigitalOcean - same droplet, different docker image - works just fine, including the use of port 80.

My Shiny code explicitly requests port 80:

```
shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(port = 80))
```

Comment: What's the error you're seeing? What's the output of "curl https://yourserver.com" ?

Comment: Connection refused: Failed to connect to 142.93.182.11 port 80: Connection refused

Answer (score 2):

Docker is binding to port 80 on the ipv6 interface only and not the ipv4 interface, you can tell from the missing `tcp *:http` entry in your netstat output.

Because of that, your connection to the ipv4 IP does not succeed and curl and others return "Connection refused".

See e.g. [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957143/make-docker-use-ipv4-for-port-binding)  issue with details how to make Docker use the ipv4 interface.