# Can't reach service of host from container

Tags: docker, networking

On the host, there is a service

```
@server# netstat -ln | grep 3308
tcp6       0      0 :::3308                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

It can be reached from remote. 
The container is in a user-defined bridge network.
The server IP address is 192.168.1.30

```
@localhost ~]# ifconfig
br-a54fd3b63acd: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:1eff:fecc:92e8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:1e:cc:92:e8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:37ff:fe9f:e4f1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:37:9f:e4:f1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34  bytes 4018 (3.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.30  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

And `ping` from container also works.

```
@33208c18aa61:~# ping -c 2 192.168.1.30
PING 192.168.1.30 (192.168.1.30) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.30: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.120 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.30: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.105 ms
```

And the service is available.

```
@server# telnet 192.168.1.30 3308
Trying 192.168.1.30...
Connected to 192.168.1.30.
Escape character is '^]'.
N
```

But the service can't be reached from the container.

```
@33208c18aa61:~# telnet 192.168.1.30 3308
Trying 192.168.1.30...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

I checked
[Make docker use IPv4 for port binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29957143/1278112) 
make sure I didn't have IPv6 set to only bind on IPv6

```
# sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only
net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0
```

[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24319662/1278112)
find my route is a little different.

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         router.asus.com 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-a54fd3b63acd
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Does it matter? Or could it be another reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the [official document](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)

> The Docker bridge driver automatically installs rules in the host
>   machine so that containers on different bridge networks cannot
>   communicate directly with each other.

I checked the `iptables` on the server, for an experiment I stopped the `iptables` temporary. Then the container can reach that service success. Later I was told, the server has been reboot recently. So guessing some config was lost after that reboot. Not familiar with `iptables` very much, and when I try

```
systemctl status iptables.service
```

It says the service is not installed. After I install and run the service,

```
iptables -L -n
```

is almost empty. Now not clue what kind of `iptables` rules can cause that messy.
But if anyone face the `ping success telnet fail` situation, `iptables` could be the place of the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker container is on a different network namespace and connected to a different interface than your host machine that's why you can't reach it using the ip `192.168.x.x`

What you need to do is to use the docker network gateway instead, in your case `172.17.0.1` but be aware that this IP might no be the same from host to host so to reproduce this everywhere and be completely sure of which is the IP you can create an user-defined network specifying the subnet and gateway and running your container there for example:

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.16.0.0/24 --gateway 172.16.0.1 dockernet
docker run --net=dockernet ubuntu
```

Also whatever service you are trying to connect here must be listening on the docker's bridge interface as well.

Another option is to run the container on the same network namespace as the host with the `--net=host` flag, and in this case you can access service outside the container using `localhost`

Comment: the `192.168.1.30` is the host machine.  Why `--subnet 172.16.0.0/24` when the docker0 is `172.17.0.1`? It doesn't work here.

Comment: If the network is not correct, how could the container `ping` host success?