# Docker listening inside the docker host for RabbitMQ but not from outside, why?

Tags: linux, docker, rabbitmq, iptables

This is how I run the `rabbitMQ` image:

```
docker run -d --restart always --hostname host-rabbit --name cg-rabbit -p 5029:5672 -p 5020:15672 -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=sample_vhost -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=sampleuser -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=samplepass rabbitmq:3-management
```

Now in `netstat -nltp`:

```
ubuntu@infra:~$ netstat -nltp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5020                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5029                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

**I'm not sure** why I see `tcp6` when docker exposes ports to host and if it makes issues!

Now when I telnet from within the server I can see that port is open:

```
ubuntu@infra:~$ telnet MY-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS 5029
Trying MY-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS...
Connected to MY-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]

telnet> Connection closed.
```

But in my machine when I try to `telnet` (or from another server):

```
$ telnet MY-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS 5020
Trying MY-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS...
^C
```

`iptables -L` reports:

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:5020
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:5029
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:amqp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:15672

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

**It is good to note that** I have installed a redis server in server (non-docker) and I am able to `telnet` to it form outside.

---

EDIT-1:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !localhost/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:15672
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:amqp

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:15672 to:172.17.0.2:15672
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:amqp to:172.17.0.2:5672
```

---

`EDIT-2:`
Docker configuration:

```
ubuntu@infra:~$ sudo cat /var/snap/docker/796/config/daemon.json
{
    "log-level":        "error",
    "storage-driver":   "overlay2"
}
```

Comment: `iptables -t nat -L` ? `docker inspect cg-rabbit`?

Comment: netstat shows this is an ipv6 address. Are you reaching your machine also via ipv6?

Comment: @TheFool no I just use ipv4

Comment: @KamilCuk please check my `EDIT-1` update

Comment: @KamilCuk I have changed to their default port for now I mean `5672:5672` and `15672:15672`

Comment: Please show your `cat /etc/docker/daemon.json`. Well, that iptables looks ok.

Comment: the file isnt there if you never configured it. Its for extra configuration. I am still wondering why it did bind on ipv6. I am not sure if it can work like that when you reach host on ipv4, but I am not super strong in networking.

Comment: @KamilCuk please check `EDIT-2` part of question for docker configuration.

Comment: @TheFool so the reason I can telnet to `redis` port is that it is `ipv4`, but docker services are on `ipv6`!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make docker use IPv4 for port binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957143/make-docker-use-ipv4-for-port-binding)

Answer (score 1):

This is really odd. By flushing the `NAT` in `iptables` everything works as expected:

```
iptables -t nat -F
```

My nat before flushing:

```
ubuntu@infra:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !localhost/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:15672
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:amqp

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:15672 to:172.17.0.2:15672
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:amqp to:172.17.0.2:5672
```

And now after flushing everything is gone:

```
ubuntu@infra:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**NOTE:** by restarting docker via `sudo snap restart docker` net rules are back again and I had to flush NATs again!

Comment: You should not flush the tables after docker did its setup. Its putting stuff there for good reason. You have a different problem which you just cover by this "hack".

Comment: @TheFool yes right, but if you have a better solution and know why this issue is raised by `docker NATs` I'm all ears :)

Comment: I don't have, and I also don't need to. its your problem. I am just pointing out that this isn't a real solution. Who knows what else is broken now because the entries' docker wants to have in the Nat table are not there. I personally would look into the ipv6 thing. For example you could try to set a fixed cdir for docker0 http://docs.docker.oeynet.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/. You can also publish the port to a specific ip address. `-p 192.168.1.100:8080:80` https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/