# How remove from docker ps in session ports the mention of ipv6 binding?

Tags: docker

I'm research to a way to remove the mention of IPv6 port binding on docker ps output, but without successes.

My first tentative was disable in docker daemon, but not works.

```
jq '.ipv6 |= false' ~/.docker/daemon.json | sponge ~/.docker/daemon.json
```

[image]

Comment: What's your goal with this?  Do you have any application code that depends on this specific output (and can you use a Docker SDK to avoid parsing the `docker ps` output)?

Comment: I used a simple example here, but with large projects, the output are hard to understand, because ports are using a lot of space of screen.

Comment: But I not wish remove the ports section from screen. This is important.

Comment: is there anything updated? I also have the same consideration like you. As I only care about the Image, Container Name, Status of the Container, Container Ports, I use this instead to use less screen: `alias dps='docker ps --format "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Ports}}"'`. But I'm looking forward to something that can cut IPv6 part of ports.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine removing the bindings to IPV6, publish your ports using `0.0.0.0` explicitly:

Instead of

```bash
docker run --publish "8080:80" nginx
docker ps -a
# CONTAINER ID  IMAGE  COMMAND                 CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                  NAMES
# 002b3e137a6d  nginx  "/docker-entrypoint.…"  13 seconds ago  Up 12 seconds  0.0.0.0:8910->80/tcp, :::8910->80/tcp  nice_lewin
```

use

```bash
docker run --publish "0.0.0.0:8910:80" nginx
docker ps -a
# CONTAINER ID  IMAGE  COMMAND                 CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                 NAMES
# 8b58a106cf26  nginx  "/docker-entrypoint.…"  4 seconds ago  Up 3 seconds  0.0.0.0:8910->80/tcp  keen_nightingale
```

**Credits**: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68332078/1862762) from Darren S