# Can't connect to postgres docker container from localhost? Port forwarding appears to not be working

Tags: postgresql, docker

Creating postgres docker container in Ubuntu 18.04 like...

```bash
docker run -it -e POSTGRES_USER="root" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi" -v /my/absolute/path/to/my/local/folder/ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw -p 5432:5432 postgres:13
```

...but getting errors like:

> OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly

when trying to connect via

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://root:root@localhost:5432/ny_taxi')
engine.connect()
```

I also can't connect when using `psql`

```
➜  ~ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U root -W
Password for user root: 
psql: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

or using `pgadmin4` from my local desktop or changing "localhost" to the value "0.0.0.0"

I see no local postgres service running:

```
➜  ~ systemctl status postgresql
Unit postgresql.service could not be found.
➜  ~ service postgresql status
Unit postgresql.service could not be found.
```

and this is the only thing that appears to be using the specified port:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
.
.
.
docker-pr 31534            root    4u  IPv6 4358622      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
```

This is also the only docker container I have running and the image was just downloaded today:

```
➜  ~ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
406c9a5efc34        postgres:13         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   affectionate_bose
```

Anyone have any ideas what could be going on here? Any debugging suggestions?

***UPDATE**

The original debug observation by @jjanes in the comments initially worked for my issue (I have now installed the lasted version of docker and containers now use both IPv4 and IPv6), but now no longer working though I don't recall changing anything since the last time I checked.

Am still / once again getting errors when running

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://root:root@localhost:5432/ny_taxi')
engine.connect()
```

with an error message

> OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
> This probably means the server terminated abnormally
> before or while processing the request.

and cannot connect to the DB with `pgadmin4` or `psql` like

```bash
➜ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U root -d ny_taxi -W           
Password for user root: 
psql: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

Yet I see now that both IPv4 and IPv6 are being used:

```bash
➜ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
.
.
.
docker-pr 29152            root    4u  IPv4 6892807      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 29164            root    4u  IPv6 6890891      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)


➜ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
47c77203991c   postgres:13   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   25 minutes ago   Up 25 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   sleepy_chandrasekhar
```

The logged output I see from the docker container is

```
2022-08-12 03:59:12.942 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.8 (Debian 13.8-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-08-12 03:59:12.942 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-08-12 03:59:12.942 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-08-12 03:59:12.954 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-08-12 03:59:12.971 UTC [62] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-08-12 03:59:12 UTC
2022-08-12 03:59:12.982 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

This log output for the DB container does not change even when trying to `psql` connect using a wrong username or password (eg. having some message about a failed login attempt) -- thus making me suspect some kind of port forwarding issue with docker.

Seems very weird. Anyone know what could be going on here? Anything I should check?

Comment: what does `docker logs 406c9a5efc34` say? My first guess would be a permission issue on the pgdata directory

Comment: Your `lsof` suggests you are only listening on IPv6 (unless you elided the relevant IPv4 line), while your error message suggests you are trying to connect over IPv4.  I don't know *why* it would only listen on IPv6, for me it listens on both.

Comment: @jjanes I see, I don't really work w/ networking issues, so this didn't pop out to me as a problem. Looking at another issue here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68332078/8236733) helped me see more what you meant that docker *should* use both IPv4 and 6 by default. Updating my version of docker (per their newest docs, https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) solved the issue. (Still debating whether to leave this question up b/c the answer is so tangent, but if you phrased it in an Answer post I'd accept it).